# difference between `catMaybe as? Animal` and `catMaybe as Animal?`

Tags: swift, casting

Lets say I have these:

```
class Animal {
}

class Cat: Animal {
    var meow = "meow"
}
```

Now I have a variable:

```
var catMaybe: Cat? = /* ... */
```

and at some point later I do this:

```
var obj1 = catMaybe as Animal? // ①
```

and it compiles fine but I could have wrote this other code too:

```
var obj2 = catMaybe as? Animal // ②
```

only this time I get a warning. Which confuses me since I thought both were doing the same.

```
warning: cast from 'Cat?' to unrelated type 'Animal' always fails
         var obj4 = catMaybe as? Animal
                    ~~~~~~~~ ^   ~~~~~~
```

What is the real difference between ① and ②?

#### Edit1

I am interested in what is really happening in the background. I would go and read the assembly code to find why ② always fails but unfortunately I am not very good at it :(

In ②, since `Animal` is not an optional, I thought the compiler would know that `catMaybe` must be unwrapped first and if the operation succeed try to cast it to `Animal`. In any case of error it would return nil (since I am using `as?`) Why the compiler does not apply this logic? What stops him?

#### Edit2

I am using swift 1.2

Comment: Try it in an if let,thingie

Answer (score 1):

With as? you cast an optional,let say you do a if let`if let object = catMaby as? Animal{
/do some code with object
}`

You are not sure if catMaby has a value.as? are for if let

***Explanation***

The optional form, as?, returns an optional value of the type you are trying to downcast to. The forced form, as, attempts the downcast and force-unwraps the result as a single compound action.So if you are not sure that catMaby is a Animal,put as?.There in the code  checked if catMaby is Animal and checked if catMaby is an optional

So as? is for optional values,as! is the same but gives an error if you try to unwrap it

Comment: *The forced form, as, attempts the downcast and force-unwraps the result as a single compound action*. That is the definition of `as!` I think

Comment: @nacho4d No,thats "as","as!" is for failable casts that can fail at runtime

Comment: from the [swift programming language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html) second paragraph
> *Because downcasting can fail, the type cast operator comes in two different forms. The conditional form, as?, returns an optional value of the type you are trying to downcast to. The forced form, as!, attempts the downcast and force-unwraps the result as a single compound action.*

Comment: Also sorry to be pedantic but the question is not about downcasting. , I am trying to cast to the super class so this is *upcasting*. The logic should the same I guess

Comment: @nacho4d As, will throw a compiler error ,if you class b isn't a subclass of class a

Answer (score 0):

You get the warning since `catMaybe` is an optional. Optionals are of an enum type and only after you unwrap `catMaybe` (with either ? or !) you will get the correct object (of type `Cat`).

Since `catMaybe` is an `enum` (which does not inherit `Animal`) you get that warning.

So this should work :

```
var obj2 = catMaybe! as? Animal // upcast the real unwrapped value
```

The first version works since you keep `catMaybe` as an optional (an optional to an `Animal` object when unwrapped)

Answer (score 0):

This is made complicated by mixing together two things – optionals, and casts.  It might be clearer to ditch the optionals, look at that, and then reintroduce the optionals.  Note this is all Xcode 6.3/Swift 1.2.

Here’s the simplest case:

```
class Animal { }
class Cat: Animal { }

let c = Cat()
let a = c as Animal  // fine
```

The compiler knows that every `Cat` reference can be guaranteed convertible to `Animal`, so it lets you use `as` without complaint.  If you do it the other way around though:

```
let a: Animal = Cat()
let c = a as Cat  // compiler error
```

The compiler complains that `as` cannot be used – an `Animal` might not be a `Cat`.  You must use `as?`, which returns an optional value – either a successfully converted `Cat`, or `nil`:

```
let a: Animal = Cat()
if let c = a as? Cat   // c will be a Cat?
```

Swift also lets you use `as?` when the conversion is guaranteed to work:

```
let c = Cat()
let a = c as? Animal  // a will be an Animal?
```

though it sometimes give you a warning that you’re using a conditional cast on something that will always succeed.  But its only a warning.

That’s pretty much it for `as` vs `as?`.  `as` for when the compiler can know for certain the cast will work, `as?` that returns an optional for when it might not.  This doesn’t just apply to super/subclasses, it also applies to other conversions guaranteed to work, such as `Swift.Array` to `NSArray`, `Sometype` to `Sometype?`.

OK now to add in the other optional.  Suppose instead you have:

```
let c: Cat? = Cat()
let a = c as Animal?  // this is fine
```

So an optional `Cat` will convert to an optional `Animal` using `as`.  This is because optionals have support for covariance – Swift looks at the *contents* of the optional being converted from, and the *contents* of the optional being converted to, and if the conversion works on the contents, it will allow the conversion.

By the way, this also works with arrays:

```
let c: [Cat] = [Cat()]
let a = c as [Animal]
```

Since `Cat as Animal` is allowed, so is `[Cat] as [Animal]`.

However, casting away the optional is *not* allowed:

```
let c: Cat? = Cat()
let a = c as Animal
```

because you cannot discard optionality using `as`, just like this isn’t allowed:

```
let i: Int? = 1
let j = i as Int
```

And replacing `as` with `as?` here doesn’t help – you still can’t do the cast, so while it might compile, the result will always be `nil` (the compiler may warn you about this).

Finally, you can also do conditional casting *inside* the optional:

```
let c: Animal? = Cat()
let a = c as? Cat?
```

but beware!  Now `a` will be of type `Animal??`, because the optional now contains an optional.  So if you ever have to do this, you’re better off doing like so:

```
let c: Animal? = Cat()
let a = c.flatMap { $0 as? Cat? }
```

Or, you would be if this didn’t crash the compiler :-(.  But the code ought to be correct.